# Pentaho multiple Job/transformation import to repository

Tags: import, repository, pentaho

I'm trying to import multiple jobs(.kjb)/transformation(.ktr) files into pentaho repository from my local folder.
Jobs in local have details in the directory section as below,

```
<directory>&#x2f;public&#x2f;DWH&#x2f;core&#x2f;Load</directory>
```

So when I try to import it, its creating folder under the repository path i'm providing while importing,
so the job is getting checked-in in **/data_migration/public/DWH/core/Load/** instead of path **/data_migration/**

Is there a way to fix this? 
Any help or direction most welcome.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. The directory gets erased when import from an XML file, and you have to `save as` to save them elsewhere than on the main repository folder. Which PDI version?

Comment: @AlainD I am able to reproduce this issue. having the `<directory>&#x2f;public&#x2f;DWH&#x2f;core&#x2f;Load</directory> 
` tag in my ktr xml, when uploading it into repo on a folder `/A/B` using the `Import Repository...` It first creates `/public/DWH/core/Load/` under `/A/B` and then loads the files into `/A/B/public/DWH/core/Load/`. BTW V7.0

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the directory settings in the XML. You need to remove the directory settings `<directory></directory>`

This will allow the runtime folder definitions to take place and that will be considered a root folder. If you need to store the files in different folders then only the subfolder may be configured in your XMLs.